# How many workflows can a SharePoint 2007 Library / List contain?

Tags: 2007, workflow, list, document-library

What is the maximum workflow can a Library & List in SharePoint 2007 can have?

Information in http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx mention that SharePoint 2010 can have 15 (for Workflow postpone threshold) and 100 (for Workflow timer batch size) but does this apply also for SharePoint 2007?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding some more details to Ciphertxt answer:

**Throttle**

You can check the default throttle setting by running the following command (assuming there is no changes to the throttle setting before):

> stsadm -o getproperty -pn workflow-eventdelivery-throttle

You can change the throttle setting by running the following command, in which you can replace 25 with the new value:

> stsadm -o setproperty -pn workflow-eventdelivery-throttle -pv "25"

**Batch Size**

You can check the default batch size setting by running the following command (assuming there is no changes to the throttle setting before):

> stsadm -o getproperty -pn workitem-eventdelivery-batchsize

You can change the batch size setting by running the following command, in which you can replace 125 by the new value:

> stsadm -o setproperty -pn workitem-eventdelivery-batchsize -pv "125"

You can do it at your SharePoint Server either by yourself or a SharePoint System Administrator.

Answer (score 2):

The default throttle is 15 and the default batch size is 100. These are default values and can be tuned accordingly based on your environment. See [Workflow Scalability and Performance in Windows SharePoint Services 3.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd441390%28v=office.12%29.aspx) for more detail.